# What is the correct term for the mouse pointer/nipple/joystick thingy in the middle of a laptop's keyboard?

Tags: laptop, mouse, terminology

I want to call it a "mouse nipple" or maybe a "joystick", although I know these are not correct.

It's different from the touchpad, which is below the keyboard and has dedicated click buttons. Instead, it sits smack in the middle of the keyboard at the bottom right corner of the <kbd>G</kbd> key and bottom left corner of the <kbd>H</kbd> key. Tapping it translates to a click and nudging it left/right/up/down controls the pointer on the screen.

What is the correct term for this thing? I'd like to google some info about configuring it, but my google fu fails without the proper name.

Comment: "annoying" sums it up for me.

Comment: Whatever it is, it kills trackpads! Love that red nub

Comment: It's always been called a 'nipple' be it a keyboard/mouse/laptop nipple... Have called them that for 8+ years and informed many thousands of others it's called such :)

Comment: It should be called a keymouse.

Comment: "What laptops should have stayed with rather then cluttering up my machine with an inaccurate and slow touchpad" I mean, really. *Tap tap tap tap* Finally at the edge of the screen. Oh wait, I clicked by accident.

Comment: We called it the clit. I'm surprised nobody else mentioned it.

Comment: The challenge is to find an appropriate term that doesn't have a sexual connotation.

Comment: The touchpad is the most epic disaster of cursor interaction ever devised. It's completely in the way. It's caused just about every laptop on the market to place their keyboards way at the back of a loooongggg palm rest so that typing involves terrible ergonomics. No driver has ever been devised that prevents the touchpad from moving the mouse, selecting stuff, and in general creating havoc while typing. And the list goes on.

The pointing stick was and still remains the pinnacle of cursor technology. Zero neck strain, ever. Zero shoulder strain, ever. Precise. Responsive. Never in the way.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[image: pointing stick]

The above device is generically called [pointing stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick):

> The **pointing stick** (trademarked by IBM as the **TrackPoint** and by Synaptics as the **TouchStyk**) is an **isometric joystick** used as a pointing device (compare especially touchpad and trackball). It was invented by research scientist Ted Selker. It is present on many brands of laptops, including Lenovo's line of ThinkPad laptops, Toshiba Tecra laptops, HP business notebooks and on Dell Latitudes under the name of Track Stick. It has also been used on computer mice and on some desktop keyboards (as an integrated pointing device).

Comment: On a side note: The first result for the Google query `mouse nipple` is actually the Wikipedia entry I quoted.

Comment: I like `mouse nipple` can I get a trademark for that?   Just think of the potential to advertise..."The Mouse Nipple 34DD is the newest improvement...in nipple technolgy."

Comment: I've always called it a `nipple`.  After all, it bears no relation to `pointing` or `stick` whatsoever.

Comment: I typically refer to it as "That IBM touch-pad replacement I used as a mouse when I completed Half-life 1 on Hard.Request clarification or suggest improvements.

Comment: The pointing stick is basically the cure for carpal tunnel syndrome. The touchpad is anything but, especially since now you have to type with your hands turned sideways in order to avoid triggering mouse movement, text selection, etc. I challenge anyone reading this with carpal tunnel syndrome to purchase a keyboard with a built-in pointing stick and report back on how the pain is in six months.

Answer (score 74):

Apparently, the thing goes by many different names...

One of the most formal names is *TrackPoint™-style pointer*.

Other less formal or abusive names can be found [on XKCD](http://xkcd.com/243) (16+, may not be safe for work).

Comment: Nub was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: "Stupid red cap that pops off and gets lost in the bottom of the bag" , "Eraser that got attacked by a Dremel"...

Comment: I wish we could up-vote edits.  I almost down-voted the original incarnation of this answer, since it was more of a joke answer than actually useful.  Now I don't want to up-vote it because the credit won't go to the person who actually made it more appropriate.

Comment: The original incarnation contained an image with the answer "TrackPoint™". I don't think "Style Pointer" is a name for it, rather a "TrackPoint™ Style Pointer" (all one name) - so if anything the edit has lessened the usefulness/correctness.
Up-voted for the original answer as it was.

Comment: IBM is (was) a big player in producing these things, and their product was called TrackPoint. So TrackPoint Style Pointer means a pointer in TrackPoint style.

Comment: It's always been the informal for me.  Like in life, the responce you get from the damn thing isn't always what you'd expect.

Answer (score 29):

There is no single correct term since there is no de-jure authority for naming of computer parts.

Different manufacturers use differrent names, you could therefore choose to regard the makers name for a thing as it's correct name

- IBM: Track Point
- Dell: Track Stick
- Toshiba: AccuPoint

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick#Naming_and_brands

Comment: Yes, I have known those things as an "accupoint" since about 1999

Comment: Indeed. The Satellite Pro got me hooked on the term "accupoint", and also single-handedly made me hate the infernal thing.

Comment: Just ordered a couple of these from the Dell Preimer website for the CIO a few days ago, they were referred to as "PointSticks"

Answer (score 18):

I like to call it the "GHB stick", since it usually resides between <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, and <kbd>B</kbd>.  However, I'm not aware of anyone else using that particular terminology.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense actually. I will adapt it, for kicks :D

Comment: Whoa, this is another weird double entendre http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-Hydroxybutyric_acid

Comment: @CamelBlues I knew it sounded familiar, but couldn't pin down why.

Comment: So would that be the "Ghib stick"?

Comment: @NathanCox Nice, but I usually just pronounce the letter likes: "gee aitch bee stick".

Answer (score 2):

XKCD aside, I've also heard it referred to as a 'pushpoint' - which I guess makes sense as a more generic term for 'trackpoint' just like 'pushpad' is a more generic term than 'trackpad'.

Comment: Can't say I've ever heard "pushpad" used in place of "trackpad", but I can see the logic.  I'm not really sure how one is particularly more generic than the other, though.  Is "trackpad" trademarked or something?

Answer (score 1):

eraser

I have heard of it being called the "eraser", or some longer phrase like "eraser pointer", "eraser controller", "eraser stick", "eraser thing", etc.  (Some implementations just look like a little red cylinder, and don't have little bumps on the top, like the bumps on the picture above.  Perhaps especially due to their commonly-red color, they look kind of like a thin pencil eraser.)

Comment: That said, I favor "pointing stick" as the most generic and technically-accepted term.  I'm just adding this to the mix as I've definitely heard this being used on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 0):

When it's clear from context that you're talking about a computer input device (so you don't need the more precise terms in Dennis's and Mark's answers), I've heard it called a **nub**.

The word *nub* is also useful to refer particularly to the separable rubber component, when you're distinguishing it from the pointing device as a unit (e.g. when replacing it).